# Method annotations appears to takes parameter names into accout

Tags: java, annotations

Consider the following code

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Auditable {
    public String value();
}

class Order {
    public static final String NAME = "ORDER";
}

public class TestAnnotations {

    @Auditable(Order.NAME)
    public void testMethod(Order Order) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

it fails to compile with error

> java: ....\TestAnnotations.java:28: attribute value must be constant

however if I change the parameter name of testMethod

> public void testMethod(**Order o**)

it compiles.

It seems that in the annotation

```
    @Auditable(Order.NAME)
```

the formal parameter is considered instead of type Order.
However I was not able to find in the documentation any reference that when annotations are processed  method parameters are in the context.

Can it be specified somehow that Order.NAME refers to type "*Order*" not the parameter (instance) "*Order*"?

Comment: It compiles fine on Eclipse, but got the same message from `javac`. Capitalized variable name (`Order`) is not a good practice and against the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: I confirm @Bhesh's comment. It seems to be, at least to some degree, a compiler issue. At the same time, if you follow the normal coding conventions pointed out in one of the other comments then this type of confusion cannot occur in the first place. Is there any reason not to?

Comment: I've got this issue in a code generated by a tool and I was curios if it can be addressed somehow.